# Clip Raster in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 writes NoData border

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, nodata

[image: When using the Identify tool, you can see the NoData pixel values surrounding the clipped raster. These pixels should have no value.]I'm trying to clip a DEM raster using a rectangular polygon shapefile as the extent.

The [Clip Raster tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) will add/write a NoData border surrounding the output raster. The NoData pixels are displayed as transparent within ArcGIS. When exported as a TIFF for further analysis outside of ArcGIS, there is a black border present.

*Does the Clip Raster tool always add a NoData border to any raster output?*

I've also tried masking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added a screenshot, hopefully this helps.

Comment: How big is the border, is it suspiciously 1 pixel wide? The tool should not create a border unless the extent of the  clipping layer is larger than the raster. Explore setting the Snap Raster Environment setting, Don't know what that is? Read the Help file.